# W3.CSS Navigation Tabs - Show 2 id

Tags: javascript, html, css, w3-css

I am using W3.CSS Navigation Tabs but I have problems. 
I have 2 id, I want to show that 2 id when people, for example, click Tab "London" then show 2 id.
In W3.CSS Navigation Tabs code, I can show only 1 id at the same time but I don't how to add 1 more id to show up

W3.CSS Navigation Tabs code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<body>

<div class="w3-container">
  <h2>Tabs in a Grid</h2>

  <div class="w3-row">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openCity(event, 'London');">
      <div class="w3-third tablink w3-bottombar w3-hover-light-grey w3-padding">London</div>
    </a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris');">
      <div class="w3-third tablink w3-bottombar w3-hover-light-grey w3-padding">Paris</div>
    </a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo');">
      <div class="w3-third tablink w3-bottombar w3-hover-light-grey w3-padding">Tokyo</div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="London" class="w3-container city" style="display:none">
    <h2>London</h2>
    <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="Paris" class="w3-container city" style="display:none">
    <h2>Paris</h2>
    <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
  </div>

  <div id="Tokyo" class="w3-container city" style="display:none">
    <h2>Tokyo</h2>
    <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, x, tablinks;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("city");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" w3-border-red", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.firstElementChild.className += " w3-border-red";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be passing multiple city names as an array instead of single city name to the `openCity` function.

In the following example, the content of 2 tabs with the id `London` and `Paris` will show up when you click on the tab *London*.

```js
function openCity(evt, cityNames) {
    let i, x, tablinks;
    
    x = document.getElementsByClassName("city");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" w3-border-red", "");
    }
  
    cityNames.map(function(city) {
        document.getElementById(city).style.display = "block";
    });
    
    evt.currentTarget.firstElementChild.className += " w3-border-red";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<div class="w3-container">
    <h2>Tabs in a Grid</h2>

    <div class="w3-row">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openCity(event, ['London','Paris']);">
            <div class="w3-third tablink w3-bottombar w3-hover-light-grey w3-padding w3-border-red">London</div>
        </a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openCity(event, ['Paris']);">
            <div class="w3-third tablink w3-bottombar w3-hover-light-grey w3-padding">Paris</div>
        </a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openCity(event, ['Tokyo']);">
            <div class="w3-third tablink w3-bottombar w3-hover-light-grey w3-padding">Tokyo</div>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div id="London" class="w3-container city">
        <h2>London</h2>
        <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="Paris" class="w3-container city" style="display:none">
        <h2>Paris</h2>
        <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
    </div>

    <div id="Tokyo" class="w3-container city" style="display:none">
        <h2>Tokyo</h2>
        <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you now works I have one more question how can I set "London" tab to show when the user visits the site? @N'Bayramberdiyev

Comment: Remove `display:none` style from the block with the id `London` and add `w3-border-red` class to the related tab link. Updated the answer.

Comment: I see problems when I add more id, I have total now 4 id and not work only work 3 id but when I add on another tab number 2 same id as on tab number 1 only I change id names, not work @N'Bayramberdiyev

Comment: What is the problem? Please make sure id values are unique and pass ids to the `openCity` which you want to activate.

Comment: Problem is when I add new id not working example I add newyork id see this link: https://codeply.com/v/O51V3dQqxb in left bottom you can see "Source" button than click that and you can see code @N'Bayramberdiyev

Comment: Okay, the problem is that you forgot to add a tab link related to the id `NewYork`. When you add a new id (content), you need to add a tab link for it as well. Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7h98xto1/). Hope this helps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207036/discussion-between-josip-valcic-and-nbayramberdiyev).